# Win UI 3 issues when using PickAFileButton_Click from the gallery

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

The error code I get indicates that the my class isn't the right type but I don't see other options as the documentation says to use this for the signature:

`public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window`

The error is where the window var declaration is, "this" is highlighted:

```
private async void PickAFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        OutputTextBlock.Text = "";
        // Create a file picker
        var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

        // Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current WinUI 3 window.
        var window = WindowHelper.GetWindowForElement(this);
        var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);

        // Initialize the file picker with the window handle (HWND).
        WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(openPicker, hWnd);

        // Set options for your file picker
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        // Open the picker for the user to pick a file
        var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            PickAFileOutputTextBlock.Text = "Picked file: " + file.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            PickAFileOutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
        }

    }
```

Error message:
CSI 503: Argument 1: cannot convert from <namespace.class> to 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.UIElement'

The code comes directly from the original repo: https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/9b0d8f6fa5062450163cd90277cc212e96064a86/WinUIGallery/ControlPagesSampleCode/System/FilePickerSample1_cs.txt

The method param is expecting an object of the same type as the class I'm using to inherit from, as per the documentation
[image]
[image]

I tried modifing the [WindowsHelper.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/9b0d8f6fa5062450163cd90277cc212e96064a86/WinUIGallery/Helper/WindowHelper.cs#L26)  file. But it's not recommended.

Comment: If `this` is a `Window`, you don't need to call `var window = WindowHelper.GetWindowForElement(this);`, just call  `var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);`

Comment: Thanks, @SimonMourier ! That worked perfectly. I wonder why Microsoft hasn't changed the example source code.
I saw this solution also on some project like [this one one Github](https://github.com/ArtemisDevGroup/Vulcan/blob/36533f8a9163f1a56483dc9af14e838fa724eb63/Vulcan/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L17). Seems to work well.

Answer (score -1):

[`static public Window GetWindowForElement(UIElement element)`](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/9b0d8f6fa5062450163cd90277cc212e96064a86/WinUIGallery/Helper/WindowHelper.cs#L53) is designed for getting the owner window of a `UIElement`.

For a `Window` object, [as @SimonMourier said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061936/win-ui-3-issues-when-using-pickafilebutton-click-from-the-gallery#comment135851967_77061936),

> If `this` is a `Window`, you don't need to call `var window = WindowHelper.GetWindowForElement(this);`, just call var `hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);`